# How do I get BottomSheets to behave like DrawerLayout

Tags: android, button, bottom-sheet

I understand the states of a `BottomSheet` (COLLAPSED/HIDDEN etc.) but I can't figure out whether (or how) it can be made to act like the `DrawerLayout` i.e. drag it into existence from hidden state. I can do it via a button, but how can I do it via 'finger-drag' ? It is collapsible via 'finger-drag', but not expandable as far as I can tell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an offset height in the parameter `app:behavior_peekHeight` for the `BottomSheet` view then you will be able to drag and expand the view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bs_peek_height"
    app:layout_behaviour="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmm, I can drag it down, but not (back) up. To be sure, what are you setting for ``BottomSheetBehavior`` ?  I have this in my .java:        View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

Comment: off-topic: how do you get line breaks into the comment ? It says '2 white space', but when I push <ENTER>, the comment posts w/o anuy change, do I use HTML instead ?

Comment: If we put 2 enter it is breaking the line.

Comment: Btw when you put the peekHeight in the layout are you able to see the bottomsheet in the bottom of the screen when collapsed. It should be visible in order to be able to drag up..

Comment: ah, I see, if I let it peek out a bit, I indeed am able to pull it up, but I was hoping to be able to pull it out even w/o any peeking, just like the DrawerLayout. Anyway, good enough. wrt to line break, when I push the first 'ENTER', the comment gets dispatched, what am I missing ?